# I am needing to plot a line in pinescript with values ranging from 0-100 in a dictionary, for each day

Tags: pine-script

I am needing to plot a line in pinescript with values ranging from 0-100 in a dictionary, for each day.

For example, August 1 I want the line to be at 40, august 2-35, august 3-38, etc..  This would be a series of entries that I manually update each day.  I apologize for the basic question, but I am not a very experienced programmer.  Thanks

Comment: That's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

> I am needing to plot a line in pinescript with values ranging from 0-100 in a dictionary, for each day.

TradingView currently doesn't have a dictionary feature. But what you can do is create a series of conditional operators that compare each day. Then when the day is say August 2, store 35 in a variable (which we then later plot on the chart).

An example of that approach is:

```
//@version=3
study(title="Example script", overlay=true)

aug18 = (year == 2018) and (month == 8)

plotValue = aug18 and (dayofmonth == 1) ? 40 :
     aug18 and (dayofmonth == 2) ? 35 :
     aug18 and (dayofmonth == 3) ? 38 :
     na // default

plot(series=plotValue, linewidth=2, style=linebr)
```

I know this isn't a perfect solution: a real dictionary feature would be much easier to work with. But this is one of the best alternatives currently possible in TradingView.